# Showing Customized bootstrap modal using datatable's buttons

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, datatables, modal-dialog

good day everybody

I'm working with web app design on ASP.NET MVC 4. I'm using DataTable for my table design and i successfully created it's buttons(in-line with it's search box)

My problem is, I dont have any clues on how to display a customized html modal by clicking those buttons.

Any Ideas will be appreciated.

Here is my html code for my table:

```
<table id="exampledatatable" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap" cellspacing="0" >
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Customer Code</th>
            <th>Customer Name</th>
            <th>Customer Type</th>
            <th>Industry Type</th>
            <th>Website</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Off Day 1</th>
            <th>Off Day 2</th>
            <th>E-mail</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Tiger</td>
            <td>Nixon</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>2011/04/25</td>
            <td>$320,800</td>
            <td>5421</td>
            <td>t.nixon@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is my script for the table's buttons:

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#exampledatatable').DataTable({
            dom: 'Bfrtip',
            buttons: [
                {
                    extend: 'copyHtml5',
                    text: '<h4 style="font-size: 13px;"><i class="fa fa-                                              plus-circle fa-x5"></i> New</h4>',
                    titleAttr: 'Create New Record'
                },  
                {
                    extend: 'csvHtml5',
                    text: '<h4 style="font-size: 13px;"><i class="fa fa-pencil fa-x5"></i> Edit</h4>',
                    titleAttr: 'Edit Existing Record'
                },
                {
                    extend: 'csvHtml5',
                    text: '<h4 style="font-size: 13px;"><i class="fa fa-trash fa-x5"></i> Delete</h4>',
                    titleAttr: 'Delete Existing Record'
                },
                {
                    extend: 'pdfHtml5',
                    text: '<h4 style="font-size: 13px;"><i class="fa fa-reply-all fa-x5"></i> Restore</h4>',
                    titleAttr: 'Restore Deleted Record'
                },
                {
                    extend: 'pdfHtml5',
                    text: '<h4 style="font-size: 13px;"><i class="fa fa-refresh fa-x5"></i> Refresh</h4>',
                    titleAttr: 'Restore Deleted Record'
                },
                {
                    extend: 'pdfHtml5',
                    text: '<h4 style="font-size: 13px;"><i class="fa fa-print fa-x5"></i> Print</h4>',
                    titleAttr: 'Restore Deleted Record'
                },
                {
                    extend: 'pdfHtml5',
                    text: '<h4 style="font-size: 13px;"><i class="fa fa-times-circle fa-x5"></i> Close</h4>',
                    titleAttr: 'Restore Deleted Record'
                }
           ]
        });
    });
</script>
```

and here is my code for my modal

```
<div id="generalCusModal" class="modal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header modal-header-employee">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h3 class="modal-title"><img class="crud" src="~/Images/profile.png" />Customer Records Management</h3>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-body">
                    <h4 class="lbl_custinfo">General</h4>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label class="col-xs-4 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-4 control-label">Customer Code</label>
                        <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-6">
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="<Auto>" disabled>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label class="col-xs-4 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-4 control-label">Customer Name</label>
                        <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-6">
                            <input class="form-control" type="text">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label class="col-xs-4 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-4 control-label">Company Type</label>
                        <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-6">
                            <select class="form-control" id="sel1" disabled>
                                <option value="">CUSTOMER</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label class="col-xs-4 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-4 control-label">Customer Type</label>
                        <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-6">
                            <select class="form-control" id="sel1">
                                <option value="" selected></option>
                                <option>WALK-IN</option>
                                <option>RESIDENTIAL</option>
                                <option>COMPANY</option>
                                <option>SCHOOL</option>
                                <option>BANK</option>
                                <option>CLINIC</option>
                                <option>RESTAURANT</option>
                                <option>HOSPITAL</option>
                                <option>HOTEL</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label class="col-xs-4 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-4 control-label">Industry Type</label>
                        <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-6">
                            <select class="form-control" id="sel1">
                                <option value="" selected disabled></option>
                                <option>ADVERTISING AGENCIES</option>
                                <option>BUSINESS PROCESS OUTSOURCING</option>
                                <option>ENTERTAINMENT COMPANY</option>
                                <option>FOOD COMPANY</option>
                                <option>TECHNOLOGY</option>
                                <option>TELECOMMUNICATION</option>
                                <option>PHARMACEUTICAL</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label class="col-xs-4 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-4 control-label">Day Off 1</label>
                        <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-6">
                            <select class="form-control" id="sel1">
                                <option value="" selected disabled></option>
                                <option>MONDAY</option>
                                <option>TUESDAY</option>
                                <option>WEDNESDAY</option>
                                <option>THURSDAY</option>
                                <option>FRIDAY</option>
                                <option>SATURDAY</option>
                                <option>SUNDAY</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label class="col-xs-4 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-4 control-label">Day Off 2</label>
                        <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-6">
                            <select class="form-control" id="sel1">
                                <option value="" selected disabled></option>
                                <option>MONDAY</option>
                                <option>TUESDAY</option>
                                <option>WEDNESDAY</option>
                                <option>THURSDAY</option>
                                <option>FRIDAY</option>
                                <option>SATURDAY</option>
                                <option>SUNDAY</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label class="col-xs-4 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-4 control-label">Email</label>
                        <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-6">
                            <input class="form-control" type="text">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label class="col-xs-4 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-4 control-label">Website</label>
                        <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-6">
                            <input class="form-control" type="text">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label class="col-xs-4 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-4 control-label"></label>
                        <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-6">
                            <textarea class="form-control" rows="4" style="min-width: 100%"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div><!--MODAL BODY-->

                <div class="modal-footer">

                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-target="#custLocationModal" data-toggle="modal" data-dismiss="modal">Next</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Clear</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: What does *"can't find reference"* mean? Also which button are you referring to?

Comment: I mean, cannot find any documentation that can help me with the issue. sorry if its misleading

Comment: But you haven't explained properly what the specific problem is

Comment: I've already edit the question. appreciate your concern.

Comment: On which button click you want to show customized `modal`? Also how should customized `modal` look like?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao I want to display the modal after the first button is clicked and with regards by the looks of the modal I've already update my question.

Comment: You mean `copyHtml5` i.e. `Create New Record` button?

Comment: yes sir........................

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might be confusing people with your `buttons` there. I'm guessing you're wanting to get access to the row when the links are clicked in the last column? Most probably to populate the modal?

[This](https://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/wLpzer8k/) should do what you need:

```
var table = $('#exampledatatable').DataTable({
    columns:[
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    {
        visible: false
    },
    {
        visible: false
    },
    {
        visible: false
    },
    {
        visible: false
    },
    null,
    null
  ]
});
    $('#exampledatatable').on("click", ".customAction", function(){
    var d = table.row($(this).parents("tr")).data();
    console.log(d);
  // Populate your modal or do whatever you need to do here...
});
```

The linked JSFiddle should give you a start, I'm not sure what to do with the block:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "UpdateCompany") |
@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteCompany") |
@Html.ActionLink("Restore", "RestoreCompany")
```

as I'm not overly comfortable with ASP.NET MVC 4 but I'm guessing you are so I'll leave it up to you to workout how to create the buttons. I'm guessing you could use a `render` function in your DataTable initialization though...

Hope that helps.

p.s. take note of the `click` event: attach it to the table itself rather than the button class or it won't be attached to buttons on subsequent pages!

Comment: Sorry to confuse you sir. but i dont need the links(at the end of each row)to populate and display a modal for me. all i want, is when i clicked one of the DataTable button a customized html modal will pop up.